# updatepanel working in terms of request and response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have 2 sets of `asp:TextBox` and `asp:Button` controls with one set inside an update Panel and another outside..

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" ID="btn1"/>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" ID="btn2"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

codebehind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox2.Text;
    }
```

Now My question is, how exactly the Updatepanel is working?

Actually I thought, on `btn1` click only the contents of UpdatePanel are sent to server as request and response comes from server to only that updatepanel.

So, I entered some text in TextBox2 and clicked `btn1`.. but surprisingly `TextBox1` text got changed to as that of `TextBox2`..

Then I thought, the entire page is sent to server as request and response comes only to that updatePanel and is updated accordingly..

Now I checked both the requests(ie., Request from `btn1` and `btn2`) in Google Chrome Developer tool.. again to my surprise, there is difference in `Content-Length` of the request..

If there are more controls outside the update panel then the `Content-Length` would be more with the request from `btn2`

Could someone put some light on this..

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. the thing here is that even though you have a UpdatePanel in the page , when a postback occurs all the contents are posted back to the server. This behaves like a normal page without  an UpdatePanel. That's the reason you have an option UpdateMode  for the UpdatePanel...

It is **UpdateMode="Always"**  and **UpdateMode="Conditional"**.

Because you did not set anything here it is Always by default, because of which the whole page was posting back...

To see the changes you were looking for after adding the UpdatePanel you need to set it to conditional and add the elements as AsynPostbackTriggers ...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" ID="btn1"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" ID="btn2"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now when you click btn1 only contents inside the UpdatePanel are posted back and can be seen in the response.

If btn2 is clicked only the contents outside the UpdatePanel are seen in the response..

Comment: I found No difference in the request and response by making `UpdateMode="Conditional"`... `UpdateMode` really makes sense when there are more than one UpdatePanel, if I am not wrong..

Comment: Nope that's not the case.. You set it to Conditional if you do not want to Update the panel when some control is invoked.. In this case you did not want the contents to refresh when btn2 is clicked.. In such cases it is helpful..Did you set EnablePartialRendering="true" on the page .. Also do you see any errors in the console section of the browser..

Comment: when `btn2` is clicked, whatever you do, it will postback the entire page to server and entire page gets refreshed.. and also by default `EnablePartialRendering` is `true`..